# Как правильно использовать npm модули из node_modules?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

Есть два скачаных модуля `Jquery` и `Vue` которые лежат в `node_modules`. Нужно использовать из в проекте (в текущем состоянии - веб страница).

Пользуясь весьма ограничеными знаниями `node` решил что это нужно сделать через `require` но ничего не получилось (Консоль выдает: `Can't find variable: require` (как мне кажется потому что браузер не может в `node`). В таком случае как же подключить их правильно?

Comment: Модули работают на Node, а не в браузере. Если нужно собирать именно для браузера, используйте сборщики типа Webpack.

Comment: То есть в браузере нужно использовать Webpack, а в каком нибудь Electrone - require?

Comment: В браузере нет вебпака. Это сборщик, который собирает из нодовских require в обычный js. Почитайте подробнее в поиске по гуглу, просто это очень объёмная тема, не формат для вопрос/ответ.

Comment: Это я понял,у меня есть представление что это.